# Feature Pyramid Network Receptive Field

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, convolution

In a Feature Pyramid Network ([paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.03144.pdf)), the last layer of any CNN (for e.g. ResNet-101) is taken and upsampled by 2,4 and 6 for P5, P4 and P3. To allow fine-grained feature maps, lateral connections from previous layers in ResNet-101 are concatenated.

In RetinaNet ([paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02002.pdf)) there are 2 more pyramid layers, P6 which is constructed by applying a 3x3 filter on the last conv. layer in ResNet-101 and P7, by applying a 3x3 filter on P6, both with a stride of 2.

All feature pyramid layer are propagated through 1 classification subnet and 1 bounding box subnet, which share the weights for all feature pyramids.

As P6 and P7 have a bigger receptive field, does the classification subnet take the biggest receptive field or the receptive field for each pyramid layer individually?

[image: RetinaNet]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming or implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say individually. The whole point of a feature pyramid is to use the features at each scale.

Comment: I would say the same, but it isn't really clear from the papers. I tried taking a deeper look into the Tensorflow Object Detection API as well as several Keras RetinaNet implementation, but none give much information away.